# Finding All Combinations of a Multidimention Array with a Max Value in C#

Tags: c#, math, multidimensional-array, combinations

Let's say I have an int[8,6] array which can have the maximum value of 255 per cell and I want to find all combinations of this array.

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?

[image: Min array, Max Array]

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot wait long enough to see all combinations. There are 256^48=3.9402006196394479212279040100144*10^115 of them.

Comment: Actually, I only need the algorithm that I can not figure out. The logic is what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For array size `N` (1D array for simpliciry, 2D case works similar) and maximum value `M` there are `M^N` possible combinations. Every combination corresponds to value in range `0..M^N-1`, so we can just walk throug this range and get combination for every value. Of course, it is possible for reasonable small values of `N` and `M`.

Python-like pseudocode:

```
int A[N]
P = M**N  #math.intpower(M, N)
for i in range(P):
    t = i
    for k in range(N):  #number of cells, number of digits in counter value
        A[k] = t % M  # value in k-th cells of result for variant number i
        t = t // M  #integer division
```

Note that for base `M=256` you perhaps don't need to use division - needed values are just bytes of multibyte representation of big number in base 256